# I am learning data structures using c, while learning stacks I tried to convert infix to postfix and wrote this code . Code is not giving output

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

I am a beginner programmer trying to learn data structures but I am currently facing problem in this particular code I spent many hours and still don't know the problem. I used pointers to enter the elements in stack, my professor directly used arrays like `infix[i]`, I don't know if my approach is wrong but I wanted to try something new.

---

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define max 100

char stack[max];
int top = -1;
char pop();
char push(char x);
int priority(char x);
void infixtopostfix(char *infix, char *postfix);

int main() {
  char infix[100], postfix[100];
  printf("Enter the expression");
  fgets(infix, max, stdin);
  infixtopostfix(infix, postfix);
  puts(postfix);
}

char pop() {
  char val;
  if (top == -1) {
    printf("underflow");
    exit(1);
  } else {
    val = stack[top--];
    return val;
  }
}

char push(char x) {
  if (top == max - 1) {
    printf("overflow");
    exit(1);
  } else {
    stack[++top] = x;

  }
}

int priority(char x) {
  if (x == '^')
    return 3;
  if (x == '*' || '/')
    return 2;
  if (x == '+' || '-')
    return 1;
}

void infixtopostfix(char *infix, char *postfix) {
  char *p, *i;
  i = infix;
  p = postfix;
  while (*i != '\0') {
    if (isalpha(*i) || isdigit(*i)) {
      *p = *i;
      p++;
      i++;
    } else if (*i == '(') {
      push(*i);
      i++;
    } else if (*i == ')') {
      while ((top != -1) && (stack[top] != '(')) {
        *p = pop();
        p++;

      }
      if (top == -1) {
        printf("invalid statement");
        exit(1);
      }
      pop();
      i++;

    } else if (*i == '+' || *i == '*' || *i == '/' || *i == '-' || *i == '^') {
      while ((top != -1) && stack[top] != '(') {
        if (priority(*i) <= priority(stack[top])) {
          *p = pop();
          p++;

        }
        push(*i);
        i++;
      }

    } else {
      printf("invalid expression");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
  while ((top != -1) && (stack[top] != '(')) {
    *p = pop();
    p++;
  }
  *p = '\0';
}
```

For input (a+b) the expected output should be ab+
but code doesn't give any output.

Comment: How have you tried to debug the issue? What did you learn from debugging?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Have you tried puts(infix); right after your fgets? Add some printf in your code to see where it’s going?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fgets(infix,max,stdin);` means `infix` may (or may not) contain the newline character (`'\n'`).

If it does, then like any other whitespace character, it will cause (in `infixtopostfix`)

```
else
{
    printf("invalid expression");
    exit(1);
}
```

to occur.

You should check the return value of `fgets`, to see if it succeeded or not and then remove the trailing newline if it exists.

See: [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2505965).

---

`priority` has the issue that its default return value is `2`, and it cannot ever return `1`, because

```
if(x=='*'||'/')
return 2;
```

is effectively parsed as

```
if((x == '*') || ('/' != 0))
return 2;
```

Fix this function to have proper comparisons, and return a *minimal* default value, e.g.:

```
int priority(char x)
{
    if (x == '^')
        return 3;
    if (x == '*'|| x == '/')
        return 2;
    if (x == '+'|| x == '-')
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

---

With the previous fixed, `(` now has a priority of zero.

The `while` condition here should drop the explicit check for `(`

```
else if(*i=='+'||*i=='*'||*i=='/'||*i=='-'||*i=='^')
{  
    while((top!=-1)&&stack[top]!='(') {
        if(priority(*i)<=priority(stack[top])) {
            *p=pop();
            p++;

        }
        push(*i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

instead, pop values as long as their priority is greater or equal to the priority of the currently scanned operator, and push the new operator *outside* the loop.

```
else if (*i=='+'||*i=='*'||*i=='/'||*i=='-'||*i=='^') {
    while((top!=-1) && priority(*i) <= priority(stack[top])) {
        *p=pop();
        p++;
    }
        
    push(*i);
    i++;
}
```

Without this change, given `(a+b)`, when `+` is scanned: the top of the stack will be `(`, and the `while` loop will never be entered (and the new operator will never be pushed to the stack, since that was *inside* the `while` loop).

With the change, `+` has a greater priority than `(`, meaning `(` won't be *popped* from the stack. `+` is then unconditionally pushed to the stack, *after* the `while` loop.

---

`char push(char x)` does not return a value. Define it as `void push(char x)`.

---

The program works with the previous changes applied

```
$ gcc infix_to_posfix.c 
$ ./a.out 
Enter the expression(a+b)
ab+
```

but could use a lot of refactoring (and formatting).

In particular, defining two functions:

- `bool is_empty(void)`, and
- `char peek(void)`

would simplify the code in several places.

For example, you have written `top != 1` or `top == -1` in several different places. What if later you decide to change the way your stack works, with a `top` of `0` now signifying an empty stack? You would have to change your code in several places.

Instead, defining the function

```
bool is_empty(void)
{
    return -1 != top;
}
```

and using it as:

```
// if (top == -1) {
if (is_empty()) {
    printf("underflow");
```

or

```
// while ((top != -1) && (stack[top] != '('))
while (!is_empty() && (peek() != '('))
```

means your code is both *easier to read* and *easier to maintain*, as changing what signifies an *empty stack* requires you to only modify `is_empty` - one function, instead of several places throughout your program.

`peek` is a function that returns the topmost element of the stack *without* popping it (does not change `top`).

Removing the global variables, and defining a [structure](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct) (`struct stack;`) would be the next step, so that you can easily have more than one stack in a program - with each stack being self-contained, and the associated functions being able to be used with *any* stack. This may not matter much for this particular program, but it is something to learn, and applies to any real library.

---

Here is an unrefined, but rather complete *example* of how one might prefer to approach this. It is not intended as a *fix* for your code, but as something to spend time studying.

In this example, `infix_to_postfix` protects against [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) when used correctly.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void fatal(const char *msg, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, msg);
    vfprintf(stderr, msg, args);
    va_end(args);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* TODO: dynamically grow stack when required (create, push on full)
 * report failures (pop/peek on empty) instead of resorting to `fatal` */
#define STACK_MAX 256
#define STACK_INIT { 0 }
struct stack {
    char elements[STACK_MAX];
    size_t in_use;
};

static bool is_empty(const struct stack *s)
{
    return !s->in_use;
}

static bool is_full(const struct stack *s)
{
    return s->in_use == STACK_MAX;
}

static char peek(const struct stack *s)
{
    if (is_empty(s))
        fatal("stack<%p> is empty\n", (void *) s);

    return s->elements[s->in_use - 1];
}

static char pop(struct stack *s)
{
    if (is_empty(s))
        fatal("stack<%p> is empty\n", (void *) s);

    return s->elements[--s->in_use];
}

static void push(struct stack *s, char c)
{
    if (is_full(s))
        fatal("stack<%p> is full\n", (void *) s);

    s->elements[s->in_use++] = c;
}

static unsigned precedence(char x)
{
    switch (x) {
        case '^':
            return 3;
        case '*':
        case '/':
            return 2;
        case '+':
        case '-':
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

#define safeguard(n, s) ((n) < ((s) - 1))

/* TODO: remove pathways to `fatal`
 * * report truncation
 * * report invalid expression
 */
static void infix_to_postfix(const char *infix, char *postfix, const size_t size)
{
    struct stack operators = STACK_INIT;
    size_t n = 0;

    for (; safeguard(n, size) && *infix; infix++) {
        /* place alphanumeric characters in the output */
        if (isalnum((unsigned char) *infix))
            postfix[n++] = *infix;

        /* push start of sub-expression */
        else if ('(' == *infix)
            push(&operators, '(');

        /* at end of sub-expression,
         * pop operators, placing them in the output until
         * start of sub-expression is reached
         */
        else if (')' == *infix) {
            while (safeguard(n, size) && '(' != peek(&operators))
                postfix[n++] = pop(&operators);

            /* pop the starting parenthesis to balance expression */
            (void) pop(&operators);
        }

        /* match operators */
        else if (strchr("^*/+-", *infix)) {
            /* while our scanned operator is of less than or equal precedence
             * to the topmost operator, pop the stack
             * and place that operator in the output */
            while (safeguard(n, size) && !is_empty(&operators) &&
                    precedence(*infix) <= precedence(peek(&operators)))
                postfix[n++] = pop(&operators);

            /* afterwards, push our scanned operator */
            push(&operators, *infix);
        }

        /* ignore all other scanned characters */
    }

    /* pop the remaining operators, placing them in the output */
    while (safeguard(n, size) && !is_empty(&operators)) {
        if ('(' == peek(&operators))
            fatal("Invalid sub-expression (unbalanced parenthesis detected)\n");

        postfix[n++] = pop(&operators);
    }

    postfix[n] = '\0';
}

#undef safeguard

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *infix = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "(a+b) * c/d ^ e";
    puts(infix);

    /* we don't care how long the input is,
     * but we certainly care how large the output buffer is,
     * in the event that the latter is too small */
    char postfix[128] = { 0 };
    infix_to_postfix(infix, postfix, sizeof postfix);
    puts(postfix);
}
```

```
$ ./a.out
(a+b) * c/d ^ e
ab+c*de^/
```

Comment: With the previous fixed, ( now has a priority of zero.

can you explain why `else if(*i=='+'||*i=='*'||*i=='/'||*i=='-'||*i=='^')
{  
    while((top!=-1)&&stack[top]!='(') {
        if(priority(*i)<=priority(stack[top])) {
            *p=pop();
            p++;

        }
        push(*i);
        i++;
    }
}` was a infinite loop before the removal of (

Comment: can you please also elaborate 
In particular, defining two functions:

bool is_empty(void), and
char peek(void)
would simplify the code in several places.

Removing the global variables, and defining a struct stack; would be the next step
a little more.

Comment: @learner I have elaborated quite a bit on both those topics. Please give the answer another read if you are still curious.

Answer (score 0):

Code has at least these problems:

**Save time, enable all warnings**

```
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Missing return in `priority()`.
`if(priority(*i)<=priority(stack[top]))` is then a problem.

Missing return in `push()`, yet later code does not use the return value.  Still poor coding.

Add a return value in all code paths.

**Infinite loop**

Hard to track down, but `while((top!=-1)&&stack[top]!='(')` looks amiss.

Comment: @greybeard Agreed, post amended.